# VBA Application.Evaluate Error 2015 Trying to Assign a formula value to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to assign the formulas value as it goes to a variable called "Days"

```
"=DATEVALUE(MID(B4,7,9))-DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A4,4),LEFT(B4,4)))+1"
```

But when I make statement as goes below i get the error 2015 from the Days variable

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Activate
Range("F4").Select
Days = Application.Evaluate("DATEVALUE(MID(B4,7,9))-DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A4,4),LEFT(B4,4)))+1")
```

My objective is to use that variable as a value to make other calculations, but first I have to assign the formula value to the Days variable.

I hope that i made myself clear, i'm not too good in english.

Comment: Can you show us what A4 and B4 cells do contain as values? Then, when you try writing or evaluating a formula, you should use comma (",") instead of ";", independent of localization. VBA will use localization when the formula will be written in the cell.

Comment: I fixed the formula syntax but it didnt help, there goes the A4 and B4 values. |
A4  = "Per卲do : 01/0" |
B4 = "9/20 - 22/09/20   Sequ麩" |
Without commas, i'm doing that to organize the values of 01/09/20 and 22/09/20 and  subtract both, later i'll use the result (22) in another formula

Comment: I would suggest you to forget about Evaluate and write pure VBA code to obtain what you need. In fact, I will post an answer able to solve your problem. At least, this is what I think in this moment... :)

Comment: Does the formula return correctly in the Worksheet?  Should I understand that your normal format would be "dd/mm/yy"? I adapted the Mid part of the code to correctly return the necessary date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
 Dim Days As Long, wsP As Worksheet

 Set wsP = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")
 Days = DateValue(Mid(wsP.Range("B4").Value, 8, 8)) - _
        DateValue(Right(wsP.Range("A4").Value, 4) & _
                 left(wsP.Range("B4").Value, 4)) + 1
 wsP.Range("F4").Value = Days 'I only suppose you need the value to be placed here.
                              ' Otherwise, I cannot understand why that cell was selected...
```

Please, take care: I modified the Mid part using `wsP.Range("B4").Value, 8, 8` instead of `wsP.Range("B4").Value, 7, 8`. I do not imagine how the formula works well in your case...

Comment: @ldsouza: Glad I could help!